# Sharing list of database tables that can be manipulated in IBM DB2

Tags: db2

I recently learnt about SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE. FINAL TABLE is one of a unique table or view provided by IBM DB2 for us to get the records of last inserted row.

However, I would like to know other than FINAL TABLE. What are other type of tables are available for us to manipulate in my program.

Comment: ...you mean other than the "regular" tables in the db?  `FINAL TABLE` is a [data-change table reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html) (a ways down).  Note that availability for this is highly dependent on platform and version.  What specific info are you looking for here?

Comment: I want to know other than FINAL TABLE, what are the other regular table in the db

Comment: ...whatever you've defined previously?  A 'regular' table is one you've previously issued a `CREATE TABLE` statement for (of if on the iSeries, defined via DDS/records).  You're holding a bunch of Legos and asking "What can I change?", and my first question is "What have you built?".

Comment: Clockwork-Muse, I am getting confused with your question. I am a real newbies in database operation as I just started working for not even 1 month.

Comment: Let's me make my question clear then. Just like normal Java Programming, We have some predefined function such as trim, concatenate, substring, sort and etc. "Final Table" in database is like a predefined table to allow me to track what are the last records inserted in local machines. I want to know what are the others predefined table available.

Comment: No, it's not.  `FINAL TABLE` is a 'virtual' (not real) table the db creates in response to/during the execution of `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements.  It doesn't exist outside of this context, and can't be modified.  RDBMSs _don't have_ 'default' tables; the only pre-existing tables are the information ones (which you can't modify directly either), esentially the equivalent of getting the list of all instantiated classes in Java.  Please read a book about databases.

Comment: Well, in that case, I want a list of 'virtual' (not real) table the db creates in response to/during the execution of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements

Comment: You need to create tables to be able to get at them in the first place, and they're there for a specific subset of uses (most applications won't need them).  They're pretty much there to be able to see what things looked like before/after the various operations completed.  Check the link in the first comment I made, that has some information on them.  What is it you're trying to do with this info?

Comment: I am just trying to expand my knowledge as these information might be useful in the future. Thanks your your help Muse, I just know another two table - "NEw and old TAble"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP needs to read a book/the documentation.